# Can I run Android Studio 3.0 without Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-developer-api

Is there a way to use Studio IDE with only Java?  I'm new to Android and I'd like to just focus on the android development experience before learning another new language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new project(application), 
[image]
When you create a new activity, 
[image]

Comment: Lol, thank you sir.  blindly following tutorials and didn't even notice these options in the setup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Kotlin is an alternative, not a replacement.

You can use whichever you want, or even both of them in a project.